# Functional keys pressed stream

Tags: scala, functional-programming, game-development

I want to connect my pure game to imprue word - literaly map keys to actions. I have came up with something like this using lazy parameter:

```
sealed trait Action
object Left extends Action
object Right extends Action
object Drop extends Action

def actionsStream(v: => Int): LazyList[Action] = {
val action: Option[Action] = v match {
  case 68 => Option(Left)
  case 67 => Option(Right)
  case 66 => Option(Drop)
  case _ => None
}

action match {
  case Some(action) => action #:: actionsStream(v)
  case None => actionsStream(v)
}
}
```

I need detect key pressed immediately. I wanted using ZIO but there is no way for such detection (zio.Console.readLn will wait for enter press). So I used some library org.jline.terminal to achieve goal of detection.

```
val terminal = TerminalBuilder.builder().jna(true).system(true).build()
terminal.enterRawMode()
val reader = terminal.reader()
```

The game itself runs as follows

```
val board = Option[Board](Board())
actionsStream(reader.read).foldLeft(board)((board2, action) => game logic here
```

Everything works fine. The problem is I am doing this for learning purposes and I feel all of this is kind of hack. It would not work with more sophisticated environement (mouse events for example). And it is probably sort of blocking. I am sure there are more recommended ways of approaching this :)